# How can I retrieve only Android contacts that have an entry in the People app?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I want to include an autocomplete textbox in an Android app with the adapter being a list of the user's contacts' display names, so I started with this:

```
    private static final String[] CONTACT_COLUMNS = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, BaseColumns._ID };

    List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACT_COLUMNS, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(0);
        contacts.add(name);
    }
    cursor.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.contact_list_item, contacts.toArray(new String[] {}));
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView txtFriends = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.newVisitFriends);
    txtFriends.setAdapter(adapter);
    txtFriends.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

The result of that query, however, returns every single contact from every source, including many duplicate names and various email addresses that may have sent an email to the user's gmail account at some point.

Is there any way I can retrieve only the contacts which appear in the People app?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should filter cr.query to contacts with phone number (ContactsColumns.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#HAS_PHONE_NUMBER